# How do I write to the Android emulator using Jenkins

Tags: android, android-emulator, continuous-integration, jenkins, file-permissions

Firstly I'm assuming the problem is due to Jenkins not having permissions to write to the Android Emulator. So that might be the first thing I would like to know. But here's the background of what I am doing, please also note that all of this works fine outside of Jenkins. The other thing to note is I have setup Jenkins to run as a service.

I have a job running in Jenkins, PULL_SCREENSHOT that installs an application and runs some tests on the Android emulator, as I've stated I'm using the Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins. In the emulator config section of the Jenkins job I'm using an existing Device that I have created using ADB.exe. The problem I'm having is the tests are supposed to create a screenshots directory using this code.

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/screenshots/";

                            File dir = new File(path);

                            if (!dir.exists()) 
                            {
                                dir.mkdirs();
                            }
```

But this directory isn't created, I've looked through the file system to see if it appeared somewhere different than normal but no luck.

This is the error from the Jenkins console.

*\users\jamiemirl.jenkins\jobs\PULL_SCREENSHOTS\workspace>adb pull /sdcard/screenshots c:/screenshots/ 
remote object '/sdcard/screenshots' does not exist
\users.jenkins\jobs\PULL_SCREENSHOTS\workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*

Comment: Stupid question: have you added an SD card in the Jenkins Android Emulator configuration?

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm using an existing emulator that I created using ADB and yes this has an SD card mounted. This is the command I normally use to fetch the screenshots 'adb pull /sdcard/screenshots c:/screenshots/', it doesn't work within Jenkins.

Comment: I've also ran this job using a Samsung Galaxy and it works fine with the Real device.